# Does thoughtfulness make us more susceptible to criticism?

Tags: thought

I have noticed that when I am in a thinking mode and someone that matters to me such as my mother criticises me I keep thinking about it throughout the day and this has a negative impact on me and my emotions. On the other hand when I decide to stop engaging in mindful thought and manage to do so it seems I am able to focus on something else or not focus at all this alleviating stress.

I wonder whether stopping oneself from thinking is a good coping strategy for dealing with criticism.